# Use bit.dev on codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Someone know how to use a bit.dev component on a codesandbox or stackblitz?

I have added it to the package.json but it still doesn't work

[Here is the codesandbox for test](https://codesandbox.io/s/singup-27ird?file=/package.json)

Comment: It's a feature request at this time, @see https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/3467

Comment: Hi, as kxo says, it's a feature request.
It's not working because the registry of @bit is not configured in code sandbox and they didn't give the option to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bit.dev is going to add a 'publish to npm' step in their tag/export.

For components without publishing, I'm hoping codesandbox will allow more repositories :)